# How ro fix "java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<String> but was:<null> "?

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to test my service and an some point I received an error when I did the assertEquals

This is my test

```
@Test
    public void createNewCommentCreatesNewDTOIfNoDTOExists() {
        CommentDTO commentDTO = mock(CommentDTO.class);
        MergedScopeKey mergedScopeKey = mock(MergedScopeKey.class);

        //set merged scope key
        sut.setInput(mergedScopeKey);
        String commentText = "commentText";

        //define behaviour
        when(commentApplicationService.createCommentDTO(mergedScopeKey, commentText)).thenReturn(commentDTO);

        sut.createNewComment(commentText);

        //test the functionality
        assertNotNull(commentDTO);
        assertEquals(commentText, commentDTO.getCommentText());

        //test the behavior
        verify(commentApplicationService).createCommentDTO(mergedScopeKey, commentText);

    }
```

And this is my method that I wanted to test:

```
protected void createNewComment(String commentText) {

        CommentDTO commentDTO = commentApplicationService.getDTOComment(mergedScopeKey);
        if (commentDTO == null) {
            commentApplicationService.createCommentDTO(mergedScopeKey, commentText);
        } else {
            updateComment(commentDTO, commentText);
        }

    }
```

Do you have any ideas what I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define behaviour:

```
when(commentApplicationService.createCommentDTO(mergedScopeKey, commentText)).thenReturn(commentDTO);
```

But in your test you call:

```
CommentDTO commentDTO = commentApplicationService.getDTOComment(mergedScopeKey);
```

This is a different method, you receive null here.

Even if you fix this, you call updateComment. It is highly unlikely that your production code sets expectations on the passed in mock, thus you will always receive null from commentDto.getCommentText()

Consider using a real class instead of a mock for DTO classes.